# connection.getProgramAccounts disabled for certain clusters on Solana?

Tags: rpc, solana, serum-dex

The RPC call, `connection.getProgramAccounts()` seems to be working for my local validator and a locally deployed program, but it shows the following error when I'm trying to fetch program accounts for Serum Dex V3, `9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin`.

```
error: {code: 410, message: "The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."}
code: 410
message: "The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."
id: "f4ea7d5f-5ff4-4707-a88d-94231f7c1698"
jsonrpc: "2.0"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behaviour?s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately normal behavior.  Because of the large number of accounts that need to be sent back, RPC nodes typically restrict the use of `getProgramAccounts`, or the whole node can fall behind.  You have a few options:

- run your own node
- provision a node through a 3rd party service that allows for `getProgramAccounts` on this program
- use a Geyser plugin to get the accounts from a separate database: https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins#overview